# How to reactively update data table using reloaded data in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I'd like to create a shiny app that displays a reactive table. I'd like to be able to simultaneously exclude certain rows plus save the excluded rows in a .Rda file on my server. The point would be to permanently exclude certain rows, so each time someone loaded the shiny app, the rows would already be excluded.

I have gotten 95% of the way there -- my shiny app displays the table and saves the excluded rows in a .Rda file on my server. When I restart the app, the correct rows are excluded, however I can't get the table to dynamically exclude the rows in the same session where I exclude them. Basically, I want to be able to press an action button and have the rows excluded immediately.

Here's the shiny app

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(

      mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput("flag"),
        actionButton("exclude", "Exclude")

      )
   )

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, fu_score = 1:10,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  if (file.exists("data/prev_exclude.Rda")) {
    load("data/prev_exclude.Rda")
  } else {

    prev_exclude <- data.frame(id = 0, fu_score = 0, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    save(prev_exclude, file = "data/prev_exclude.Rda")

  }

  df_flag <- reactive({ 
    df %>%
      anti_join(., prev_exclude, by = c("id", "fu_score"))
  })

  output$flag <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df_flag(), options = list(paging = FALSE))
  })

  selected_prev <- eventReactive(input$flag_rows_selected, {
    data.frame(id = df_flag()$id[c(input$flag_rows_selected)],
               fu_score = df_flag()$fu_score[c(input$flag_rows_selected)])

  })

  observeEvent(input$exclude, {

    prev_exclude <- isolate(bind_rows(selected_prev(), prev_exclude))
    save(prev_exclude, file="data/prev_exclude.Rda")
    load("data/prev_exclude.Rda")
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Again, I'd like to be able to 1. exclude rows from the displayed table during my session (ie press an action button and have the rows deleted) and 2. save the excluded rows for future exclusion. My code handles the second piece, however it does not exclude the rows during my session (only upon reload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out! I needed to store the prev_exclude data frame into a `reactiveValues` object.

Here's the worked example

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("flag"),
    actionButton("exclude", "Exclude")

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, fu_score = 1:10,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  if (file.exists("data/prev_exclude.Rda")) {
    load("data/prev_exclude.Rda")
  } else {

    prev_exclude <- data.frame(id = 0, fu_score = 0, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    save(prev_exclude, file = "data/prev_exclude.Rda")

  }

  prev_exclude_reactive <- reactiveValues(rv = prev_exclude)

  df_flag <- reactive({ 
    df %>%
      anti_join(., prev_exclude_reactive$rv, by = c("id", "fu_score"))
  })

  output$flag <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df_flag(), options = list(paging = FALSE))
  })

  selected_prev <- eventReactive(input$flag_rows_selected, {
    data.frame(id = df_flag()$id[c(input$flag_rows_selected)],
               fu_score = df_flag()$fu_score[c(input$flag_rows_selected)])

  })

  observeEvent(input$exclude, {

    prev_exclude <- isolate(bind_rows(selected_prev(), prev_exclude_reactive$rv))
    save(prev_exclude, file="data/prev_exclude.Rda")
    load("data/prev_exclude.Rda")

    prev_exclude_reactive$rv <- prev_exclude

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope someone else comes across this and finds it useful.